# Store File Path in MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, html5-video

I am building a little social network in order to help myself better learn PHP and MySQL. Everything is working fine, including the ability to upload a video.  The video goes into the file folder that I want. The issue I am having though is that the file path is not storing in MySQL.  I have searched far and wide and tried everything that everyone else has said works for them. I have tried setting up the MySQL row type as both varchar and text.  The field name is filePath . Help is greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need more info. 
 Here is my PHP code for the file upload

```
if (isset($_POST['text']))
{
    $first = sanitizeString($_POST['first']);
    $last = sanitizeString($_POST['last']);
    $location = sanitizeString($_POST['location']);
    $web = sanitizeString($_POST['web']);
    $text = sanitizeString($_POST['text']);
    $text = preg_replace('/\s\s+/',' ',$text);
       $vidName = $_FILES['vid']['name'];
$vidTmp = $_FILES['vid']['tmp_name'];
$vidSize = $_FILES['vid']['size'];
$filePath = "uploadvideo/".$vidName;
move_uploaded_file($vidTmp, $filePath);

    if (mysql_num_rows(queryMysql("SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE user='$user'")))
    queryMysql("UPDATE profiles SET first='$first', last='$last', location='$location', web='$web', text='$text', filePath='$filePath'  where user='$user'");
    else queryMysql("INSERT INTO profiles VALUES('$user', '$first', '$last', '$location', '$web', '$text', '$filePath')");
}
```

And here is my form

```
<form method='post' action='profile.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<h3>Enter or edit your details and/or upload an image</h3>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<span class='fieldname'>First Name<span style="color:#FF0000;">*</span>:</span>
</td>
<td>
<input type='text' maxlength='23' name='first' value='$first'  /><span id='info'></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<span class='fieldname'>Last Name<span style="color:#FF0000;">*</span>:</span>
</td>
<td>
<input type='text' maxlength='23' name='last' value='$last'  /><span id='info'></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<span class='fieldname'>Location:</span>
</td>
<td>
<input type='text' maxlength='30' name='location' value='$location' placeholder="ex.(City,State Country)"/><span id='info'></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<span class='fieldname'>Website:</span>
</td>
<td>
<input type='text' name='web' value='$web' /><span id='info'></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign='top'>Summary of Your<br/ > Movement<br />(Limit to 200 Characters)<span style="color:#FF0000;">*</span>:</td>
<td valign='top'>
<textarea name='text' cols='50' rows='3' value='$text'>$text</textarea></td>
</tr>

</table>

_END
?>

Image: <input type='file' name='image' size='14' maxlength='32' /><br />
Video: <input type='file' name='vid' id='file' size='14' maxlength='32' /><br />
<input type='submit'  value='Save Profile' />
</form>
```

Comment: and the error mysql is returning is?

Comment: `queryMysql()`? should it be `mysql_query()`?

Comment: is `user` a unique/primary key? Instead of doing a `if(SELECT)UPDATE;ELSE INSERT;` you could just do a `INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`

Comment: MySQL isn't returning an error. The form submits the filePath is just not entered into the row

Comment: What gets inserted into the table? Just some values or is only the path missing.

Comment: Only the path is missing. All other values are inserted

Comment: Yes. I think I may have realized what I did. I have to call it a night though. I'm going to fire up everything in the morning though and if it works I'll let everyone know. Thanks for looking at this, but take a break for a while.